# Remove Image Tag of a string in R

Tags: regex, r

Here is a piece of strings after I xpathSapply() a xml file into R.

```
test <-
"Nothing screams the holidays quite like a honey baked ham from the infamous < a href=\"http://www.honeybaked.com/\">Honey Baked Ham Co< /a>. This molasses-y monstrous brown sugar encrusted pork dream come true was a staple at my family Christmas dinner table. Did you know that this artery clogging bit of Americana makes plenty of trimmings to pair with that big ole ham? HBH Co. is now serving up some killer casseroles to pair with that sugar-soaked pig-pile you’ve had good and bad dreams about.\n\nNow I know what you’re thinking, what does honeyed ham or a bunch of beautiful casseroles have to do with wine? Quiet thy fluttering heart… I give you the FIVE wine pairings for the perfect Honey Baked Ham Co. Holiday feast!\n\n&nbsp;\n\n<strong>1)</strong>"
```

My boss asked me to count number of words in this string, but I need to remove the image first.

I try to remove the image in this string, this:

```
< a href=\"http://www.honeybaked.com/\">Honey Baked Ham Co < /a>
```

I am new to regular expression and try `unlist(strsplit(test, split = " "))` first and then grep the index of `"< a"` and `"a>"`, and then remove everything between these two index. 
But is there any efficient way to do this?

Comment: Please mark the code as a code.

Comment: Do you want to leave the company name "Honey Baked Ham Co" in the sentence?  Otherwise the sentence would be incomplete.

Comment: OK, thank you for helping me. I will be careful next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, remove everything between and within "<" and "/a>" with sub:

```
cleared <- sub("<.*/a>", "", test)
```

Then, simply count the words:

```
wordsCount <- length(unlist(strsplit(cleared," ")))
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It actually solves my problem! I think I need to learn more about regular expression. : )

Comment: If possible, can you explain the regular expression you used?

Comment: It is the simplest regular expression possible. Dot means "any character", and "*" means "any count of it". So it will match any string with any amount of any characters enclosed between "<" and "/a>.

Comment: Yeah, I just got it. Thank you anyway!

Comment: For this code, if there are multiple image tags in the text, it won't work. When I try to test it, it will remove everything in between the first < and last a>.

Comment: Sorry, this is what happens, when you type code fast without checking if it actually works. The question is, whether you want to keep pure text within tags. If yes, you can remove opening tags with:

test1 <- sub("(<[^>]*>)","",test)

and then remove closing tags with:

clean <- sub("(</[^>]*>)","",test1)